# casting between base class and child classes

Tags: c#, casting

I have a question about casting between a base class and its child classes:

(1) Why is this allowed?

```
BaseClass b = new ChildClassA();
ChildClassA c = (ChildClassA)b
```

(2) Why is this not allowed?

```
ChildClassA c = (ChildClassA)new BaseClass();
BaseClass b = (BaseClass)c;
```

(3) Why is this allowed?

```
BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
ChildClassA c = (ChildClassA)c;
```

(4) Why is this allowed?

```
ChildClassA c = new ChildClassA();
BaseClass b = (BaseClass)c;
```

Comment: Note that (2) *is* allowed by the compiler - but you'll get a `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasons the cast is either allowed or not allowed is the basics behind inheritance.

A child class (or a derived class) is always a base class, but the opposite is not true.

To explain, let's use some more real world names for your example classes:

```
class Animal
{
}

class Dog : Animal
{
}

class Cat : Animal
{
}
```

So for your example (1):

```
Animal b = new Dog();
Dog c = (Dog)b
```

This is true because all Dogs are Animals and your Animal b is actually a dog so the cast is successful.

For your example (2):

```
Dog c = (Dog)new Animal();
Animal b = (Animal)c;
```

This is impossible because you are assigning an Animal object to a Dog, but you know that not all animals are Dogs, some animals are cats.

And for examples (3) & (4):

```
Dog c = new Dog();
Animal b = (Animal)c;
```

This is the same as your example 1 above.  All dogs are animals, so any dog can be classified as an animal and cast  (in fact you don't need the cast, there would be an implicit cast and you can write it as `Animal b = c;`

Comment: I don't knwo why I was going to edit my answer and I wanted to use the dog example too. I think in the teaching world animal stay at programming as bee stay at sex

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Why is this allowed? BaseClass b = new ChildClassA(); ChildClassA
>   c = (ChildClassA)b

Because ChildClassA IS a BaseClass.

> (2) Why is this not allowed? ChildClassA c = (ChildClassA)new
>   BaseClass(); BaseClass b = (BaseClass)c;

Because a BaseClass IS NOT a ChildClassA

> (3) Why is this allowed? ChildClassA c = new ChildClassA(); BaseClass
>   b = (BaseClass)c;

Because ChildClassA IS a BaseClass.

> (4) Why is this allowed? ChildClassA c = new ChildClassA(); BaseClass
>   b = (BaseClass)c;

Same as question 3.

When you create an inherited class, the class can be casted to an instance of the base class because it is a child of that class. However, when you try to create a child class with a base class object, the base class does not have all of the information of the child class.

**The child knows what about its parent, but the parent does not know what the child has.**

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of "is a". We can say any instance of `ChildClassA` "is a" `BaseClass` where `class ChildClassA : BaseClass`. But it is not true for vice versa. We can not say any instance of `BaseClass` "is a" `ChildClassA` in this case

Now try reading your lines of codes as follows. I believe it will make more sense this time.

`new ChildClassA()` is an instance of `ChildClassA` then it also "is a" `BaseClass`. So we can assign  `new ChildClassA()` to `b` which is of type `BaseClass`

We can cast `b` to `ChildClassA` because it actually (points) a instance of `ChildClassA`.

We can not cast `new BaseClass()` to `ChildClassA` because instance of `BaseClass` "is not a" `ChildClassA`

Answer (score 0):

Well...

(2) is not allowed, because you cannot cast a `BaseClass` to a `ChildClassA` - an instance of `ChildClassA` is by inheritance also a `BaseClass` but not the other way around!

Answer (score 0):

1. is allowed because b is indeed a ChildClassA
2. is not allowed because you can't cast a baseclass to a childClass since  baseClass don't contain the definition needed by childClass to work
3. is allowed because ChildClass contain all the definition for BaseClass and a ChildClass IS A BaseClass
   4.same as 3?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's because ChildClassA might have defined things that BaseClass doesn't know about, whereas, because ChildClassA derives from BaseClass, it knows everything about it.